# Laravel 5.5 validate unique email with model custom id

Tags: validation, laravel-5, model, unique

How do you validate unique email where model has a custom id.Here is my validation rule on update

```
'email' => 'required|unique:accounts,email,' . $user->account_id,
```

but this fails with sql error `Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'`

id should be `account_id`

here is the attempted query

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `accounts` where `email` = test@test.com and `id` <> 2445
```

Comment: what's come in error ?

Comment: as Highlighted in post `Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'` id should be account_id

Comment: what is the value of $user->account_id

Answer (score 1):

making some researches I found the following which would validate on custom index a unique requirement as Rule

```
'email' => ['required',
        Rule::unique('accounts')->ignore($user->account_id, 'account_id')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'email' => 'required|unique:accounts,email,'.$user->account_id.',my_custom_user_id'
```

Specify the ID of the table you are trying to alter. It's often a custom ID.